# Signal the end of jobs on the Queue?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, message-queue, python-multithreading

Here's an example code of from Python documentation:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

I modified it to fit my use case like this:

```
import threading
from Queue import Queue

max_threads = 10

q = Queue(maxsize=max_threads + 2)

def worker():
  while True:
    task = q.get(1)
    # do something with the task
    q.task_done()

for i in range(max_threads):
  t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
  t.start()

for task in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
  q.put(task)

q.join()
```

When I execute it, debugger says that all the jobs were executed, but q.join() seems to wait forever. How can I send a signal to the worker threads that I already sent all the tasks?

Comment: Possible typo in the latest for: is your intention to put `task` in the queue when the loop variable is `tasks`? I don't think so...

Comment: Queue up tasks that contain thread.exit()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q.join()` actually returns. You can test that by put `print("done")` after the `q.join()` line.

```
....
q.join()
print('done')
```

Then, why does it not end the program?
Because, by default, threads are non-daemon thread.

You can set thread as daemon thread using [`<thread_object>.daemon = True`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading#threading.Thread.daemon)

```
for i in range(max_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True # <---
    t.start()
```

According to [`threading` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading):

> **daemon**
>
> A boolean value indicating whether this thread is a daemon thread
>   (True) or not (False). This must be set before start() is called,
>   otherwise RuntimeError is raised. Its initial value is inherited from
>   the creating thread; the main thread is not a daemon thread and
>   therefore all threads created in the main thread default to daemon =
>   False.
>
> The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are
>   left.
>
> New in version 2.6.

Comment: I actually noticed it a while later, comparing it to the code from the documentation. Thanks! ;)

Comment: In this example, do the daemon worker threads live on forever after the main Python process terminates?  Or are they cleaned up somehow?

Comment: @TravisBear, If there are only main thread and daemon thread, and main thread end, the program end. But if there's any non-daemon thread, it will not end.

Answer (score 3):

I defined a `DONE` object to signal the end of work:

```py
DONE = object()
```

and literally put it into the queue when the upper level knows that no more data will come:

```py
q.put_nowait(DONE)
```

in the worker thread, as soon as the object is received, the thread quits.
But in case there are other threads listening on the very same queue, we have to put the object back on the queue:

```py
item = q.get()
if item is DONE:
    q.put_nowait(DONE)
    return
```

cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

This process doesn't finish at `.join()` because the worker threads continue waiting on new queue data (blocking `.get()`)

Here is a method that uses a simple flag `finishUp` to tell workers to exit, which we set after `.join()` is done - meaning all tasks are processed. I added a timeout in the `q.get()` call to allow it to check on `finishUp` flag

```
import threading
import queue

max_threads = 5
q = queue.Queue(maxsize=max_threads + 2)
finishUp = False

def worker():
    while True:
        try:
            task = q.get(block=True, timeout=1)
            # do something with the task
            print ("processing task for:"+str(task))
            q.task_done()
        except Exception as ex: # we get this exception when queue is empty
            if finishUp:
                print ("thread finishing because processing is done")
                return

for i in range(max_threads):
  t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
  t.start()

for task in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
  q.put(task)

print ("waiting on join")
q.join()
finishUp = True  # let the workers know that they can exit
print ("finished")
```

this produces the following output:

```
waiting on join
processing task for:a
processing task for:b
processing task for:c
finished
thread finishing because processing is done
thread finishing because processing is done
thread finishing because processing is done
thread finishing because processing is done
thread finishing because processing is done

Process finished with exit code 0
```